# Filtering the posts in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I want to implement the three types of filter on Wordpress post page of certain category through Ajax and jquery.

1. date range filter (from and to dates to be filled by user )
2. tag filter (a dropdown menu of tags)
3. Search (normal text filter)

These filters will query only posts of certain category not whole site . 
Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: means fliter by search functionality.??

Comment: it means it will search  particular text entered in text box  in all post title and content

Comment: Try this two plugins.
i)https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi (Search )
ii)https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-filter (filtering)

Comment: tried them ,both of them search the whole site ,they do not use ajax which is included in only Search and Filter Pro(Premium) not search and filter